# What's the proper way to (APA) reference a settlement agreement?

Tags: citations, university, writing-style, citation-style, law

I want to reference an exhibit from the following document (it's been split into separate parts):

Exhibits:
https://targetbreachsettlement.com/Portals/0/Documents/Settlement%20Agreement%20Exhibits.pdf

Agreement:
https://targetbreachsettlement.com/Portals/0/Documents/Settlement%20Agreement.pdf

---

Part of a class action lawsuit settlement agreement proposal / notice.

Court: UNITED STATES DISTRICT COURT
District: DISTRICT OF MINNESOTA
Case & MDL: 14-MD-2522-PAM/JJK
Document: 358-1
Filed: 03/18/15

Pursuant to: 28 U.S.C. § 1715

---

But I'm unsure of the proper rules to format such a citation.
I can't seem to find any information regarding the APA style for referencing settlement agreements and/or proposals in particular.

PS: More info on the settlement can be found here: 
https://targetbreachsettlement.com/mainpage/Home.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to the [table of contents](https://www.apastyle.org/manual/table-of-contents.pdf) (pdf) for the APA 6th edition style guide, the APA defers reference styles for legal materials such as court decisions, statutes, legislative materials, and administrative and executive materials to [The Bluebook®](https://www.legalbluebook.com), which requires a purchase.

However, the APA Style has a blog, which has about 10 posts tagged [legal](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/legal/), which gives guidance for a generic Name v. Name court case as follows:

> Name v. Name, Volume Source Page (Court Date)
>   e.g.
>   Lessard v. Schmidt, 349 F. Supp. 1078 (E.D. Wis. 1972)

And for the in-text citation:

> Name v. Name (Year)
>   or
>   (Name v. Name, Year)
>   e.g.
>   Lessard v. Schmidt (1972)
>   or
>   (Lessard v. Schmidt, 1972)

A settlement is just a specific type of court decision, is it not?

Comment: I don't think these documents are actually official legal documents administered by the court. The site is supervised by the court, but I think the settlement/proposal was drawn up by the defendants lawyers. I'm not sure, law isn't my area, the case just happens to be relevant to something else that i'm working on.